# Error:Connection timed out: connect - Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, connection, android-gradle-plugin

So I just installed Android studio and ran the "Hello World" basic app.

I then got this error:

> Error:Connection timed out: connect

I tried deleting the gradle from my `USER` folder (Doesnt help).

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If android studio need network access the problem probably come from your company proxy. do you have an alternative connection ?

Comment: No alternate connection, is there a way to fix this problem while still being in the same network connection ?

Comment: Well I used android studio just a few times in the past so I don't know if I  can help you. Why does it need network access for simple hello world ?

Comment: Oh and maybe you other devs in your company have a solution because I would have really have trouble to work as a dev without an alternative way  so I would be surpise you have no way to solve this proxy issue (if it's really the problem).

Comment: I guess it needs network access to download the gradle.

Comment: Well my guess is that the problem come from your company network but I don't know these tools well enough to help you. I suggest you to add gradle tag and see if someone can help you make it work "offline". If not you will have to ask question around you to solve the proxy issue

Comment: Alright, i guess that's only fair. Thanks a lot for your help tho :)

Comment: Good luck. I hope you can find a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the proxy settings in android studio to manual proxy and enter the company proxy. That helped me.

```
File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy -> check Manual proxy configurations. Enter the proxy -> click apply
```

Note** Check the connection after entering the manual proxy by clicking on `Check Connection`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the below lines in the `gradle.properties` file for the https setings configuration

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```