# Add Google Play Services for Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

I want to use Google Analytics based on below link. I should to add google play services library to dependencies in gralde. I add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0` but after 22 second, i get a connection timed out: connect error. I have a slow connection and i used proxy. I installed `google play services` version 46 and `Google repository` version 23.0.0 from sdk tools. How can i solve my problem? How can i add google play services to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may follow the steps in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071103/5832311). Try to change the proxy settings in Android Studio to manual proxy and enter the company proxy.

```
File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy -> check Manual proxy configurations. Enter the proxy -> click apply
```

> Note** Check the connection after entering the manual proxy by clicking on Check Connection.

Follow the steps in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) on how to set up your project with the Google Play services SDK.