# ERROR: Connection timed out: connect in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Gradle built failed

```
ERROR: Connection timed out: connect
```

[image: Here is my image]

Comment: That means your internet connection is slow or may be disconnected in between

Comment: Connect to proper internet having good speed

Comment: If building for the first time then it must require good internet speed and takes time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Connection timed out: connect - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266067/errorconnection-timed-out-connect-android)

Comment: possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266067/errorconnection-timed-out-connect-android

Answer (score 3):

You should add the below lines in the "gradle.properties" file for the https setings configuration

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.yourhost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser= id
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```